# How to remove a column or a row of a matrix in SymPy with keeping the original one

Tags: python, sympy

I want to remove a column from the matrix and I want to keep original one but whenever I use command `col_del()` it deletes all columns of matrices even if I rename another one. For example:

```
q=sp.Matrix([[x,x+1],[x-1,x+2]])

display(q)

w=q

display(w)

w.col_del(0)

w1=w

display(w1)

display(w)

display(q)
```

If I delete column for `w` , it also deletes column of `q` which I want it to be unchanged. How can I keep the original one?

Answer (score 1):

to understand what `w=q` means, I suggest you watch [this talk](https://rhodesmill.org/brandon/talks/#plummeting-cliff) by Brendan Rhodes. In short, `w` and `q` point to the same object, so removing something from the one, removes it from the other too

```
w = c.copy()
```

might solve your trouble

Answer (score 0):

[Variables and Other References In Python](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-in-a/0596001886/ch04s03.html)

Change your code here:

```
w=q.copy()
```

[SciPy numpy.matrix.copy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.copy.html)